# Delete items with event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to delete all my items except Select value from menu id when the user clicks above a dropdown menu, for that I did an event.

This what I tried:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let sonsLength = menu.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < sonsLength; i++) {
    if (menu[i].value != "Select") {
      menu.removeChild(menu[i]);
      sonsLength = sonsLength - 1;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<select id="menu">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="Madrid">Madrid</option>
  <option value="Barcelona">Barcelona</option>
  <option value="Sevilla">Sevilla</option>
  <option value="Bilbao">Bilbao</option>
  <option value="Manchester">Manchester</option>
  <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
</select>
```

However my loop it doesn't work how I supposed, because the user needs to click several times above the dropdown menu to delete all items except the first one and because of my understanding it should be delete the items when the user clicks once.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want the select option to stay and delete the  rest of them right? (during the click event on the dropdown menu)

Comment: Where's the button you mentioned?

Comment: @DhanaD. i think he's talking about the dropdown menu, as he is listening to the click event of the menu

Comment: Hi Dhana I had a mistake it's a dropdown menu instead a button.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @javi-ur96 run the code snippet and tell briefly whats the problem...

Comment: Yes, you're right @Ghost

Comment: @javi-ur96 when i edited the question, your code returned a syntax error at the last line, which i removed at the edit, and it starts to listen to the click event properly, is that what you want?

Comment: It seems when I click once it deletes some items and the rest still on my dropdown menu. It's weird..

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: What _items_? Do you have HTML markup of a list of cities, and when you select one city from the dropdown only that city's information should be displayed? You should update your question with a [mcve]. Deleting options from a dropdown, which is what you're doing, is odd.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure if this is what you want to achieve but maybe I am right?

```js
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

menu.addEventListener("change", () => {
  let sonsLength = menu.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < sonsLength;) {
    if (menu[i].value != "Select") {
      menu.removeChild(menu[i]);
      sonsLength = sonsLength - 1;
    }
    else
        i++;
  }
})
```

```html
<select id="menu">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="Madrid">Madrid</option>
  <option value="Barcelona">Barcelona</option>
  <option value="Sevilla">Sevilla</option>
  <option value="Bilbao">Bilbao</option>
  <option value="Manchester">Manchester</option>
  <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
</select>
```

Answering your question about the else in the for loop:

If you remove an item in an array, all other item indexes move one position forward. E.g.

You have an array

[0, 1, 2]

Now the value 0 is at index 0, the value 1 is at index 1 and the value 2 is at index 2.

When you now remove the first element you get

[1, 2]

So now value 1 is at index 0 and value 2 is at index 1.

For my loop that means, if you remove an element from the array, you must not increment the index (i) because all other elements are moving to the actual index (i). Only if I leave an element I have to increase the index to get to the next element

Comment: It doesnt delete anything

Comment: It’s deleting everything but the select

Comment: oh yeah, ur right, it deletes after choosing an option, but i dont know whether javi wants this or not

Comment: Yes it’s still unclear what his real goal is

Comment: It seems it's working, althought which is your purpose to write i iterator inside else statement? I don't understand too much. @Ghost Ops

Comment: @javi-ur96 Claus did it, not me!

Comment: Yes I apologize I mean @Claus

Comment: @javi-ur96 why are you trying to remove options from a dropdown? If you remove them they won't be available anymore and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @javi-ur96 I have edited my post to try to explain the else part of the loop

Answer (score 0):

```js
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

menu.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let selectedValue=event.target.value;
  menu.innerHTML=`<option value=${selectedValue}>${selectedValue}</option>`;
})
```

```html
<select id="menu">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="Madrid">Madrid</option>
  <option value="Barcelona">Barcelona</option>
  <option value="Sevilla">Sevilla</option>
  <option value="Bilbao">Bilbao</option>
  <option value="Manchester">Manchester</option>
  <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
</select>
```

**Changes**

- I have used the select event
- used event listner to get the selected value
- used innerHtml to replace all your option tag with the selected one